# Asynchronous programming in IntelliJ vs Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, intellij-idea

I like to test programming concepts using these 2 IDEs, however, I cannot help to notice that the `Main` function in IntelliJ has some differences compared to the `OnCreate` function in Android.

**IntelliJ**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
println("Before launch")

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    println("Launch working")
    flow.collect {
        println("Collect: $it")
    }
}
}
```

**Results**

```
Before launch
```

This is understandable as I need to use the `join` on the `job` object in order to get the `coroutine` to wait for the `Child coroutine` to be finished. The code below works fine.

Something like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
println("Before launch")

var job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    println("Launch working")
    flow.collect {
        println("Collect: $it")
    }
}
job.join()}
```

However in the Android Studio `OnCreate` function I do not need to use the `join` method to wait for the `coroutine` to finish.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    requestNews(GENERAL, generalNews, "us")
    requestNews(TECHNOLOGY, TechNews, "us")
    requestNews(HEALTH, healthNews, "us")
    requestNews(SPORTS, SportsNews, "us")
    requestNews(ENTERTAINMENT, EntertainmentNews, "us")
    requestNews(SCIENCE, ScienceNews, "us")
    requestNews(BUSINESS, BusinessNews, "us")
}

}}
```

The above code in Android Studio `OnCreate` function works,all of the `requests` were initiated. I did not have to use `job.join` to wait for the `coroutine`. Is there a reason why there is a difference in the way it works?

IntelliJ requires the need of using the `job.join` function to execute child `coroutines` properly while `OnCreate` doesn't, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating IDEs and target platforms in your question description.

- IntelliJ is not a type of app. It's an IDE for writing apps of all kinds.
- You can build Android apps in IntelliJ IDEA.
- You can build JVM apps in Android Studio (although it doesn't provide a new project wizard for creating a project specifically for that).

So your question is really about the difference between a JVM app and an Android app.

A JVM app works by executing the `main` function, and it terminates once the `main` function returns. So, if you start some asynchronous work without waiting for it, then the app will be terminated before the asynchronous work finishes.

An Android app works by looking at the app's manifest for the Activity associated with the launcher. Then it constructs the associated Activity subclass and sets up its Context and other dependencies, and then starts its lifecycle, which includes the `onCreate()` function. The Activity is not terminated until some user action like backing out of it or rotating the screen, or you calling `finish()`. The Application process (which was hosting the Activity) is not terminated until the OS decides to, or the user force closes it through the Android settings.

This is a simplification of how Android works. An app doesn't necessarily even need to have any launcher activity. It could be just a service. And the launcher activity is not the only way the application might be started.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Just a single concept:
When we are talking about the Idea's app it finishes with the `main()` function.
But the Android app (especially `Activity`) will still be running.

Furthermore, `lifecycleScope` is bound to the `Activity` lifetime so your job will be canceled when the `Activity` will be destroyed. Thus `onCreate()` won't cancel the job.